# Validate Text box in a Gridview for the selected checkBox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

can anyone help me with below query.

I have a gridview which consists of 4 columns.

column 1 - Item-template is a checkbox to check the row

column 2 - Item-template is a label  filed to display serialnumber

column 3 - Item-template is label filed to display description

column 4 - Item-template  is a textbox which allows user to enter quantity value in grid.

When i check a row in the grid i want to validate the respective  textbox of this row that it should not be empty. I found script to check at least one checkbox should be checked in grid , but i want to validate the textbox of the checked check box.

here is my gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdtest1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive table-condensed" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" slNumber">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="serialNumber" Text='<%# Eval("SL_NUMBER").ToString()%>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText=" Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <%# Eval("Description").ToString()%>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" CssClass="form-control input-sm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet that adds a listener to `GridView1` and then when a checkbox is checked it will validate the TextBox in the same row for a value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                var txt = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]');
                if (txt.val() == "") {

                    //textbox is empty
                    txt.attr('style', 'background-color:red');

                }
            }    
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your Gridview, you could do the following: (Comments for explanation)

```
//On the change of a checkbox within a table-cell
$("table tbody tr td input[type='checkbox']").on("change", function() {

    var $t = $(this);

    //If checkbox is checked
    if ($t.is(":checked")) {

        //Get its parent row
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

        //Look for a textbox within that row
        var $textbox = $row.find("input[type='text']").first();

        //Check if that textbox empty
        if (!$textbox.val().trim().length) {
            //TEXTBOX IS EMPTY
            alert("Textbox is empty.");
        }

    }

});
```

As a piece of advice, when doing JavaScript and ASP, it's always easier to work with the rendered HTML instead of the ASP itself, being as that's what the JavaScript is seeing.